# Worst Case Running time

Tags: recursion, big-o, time-complexity

I have the following Code Fragment:

```
public static boolean sumSearch(int[] a, int n, int x) {
    if (n == 0) {
         return ( x==0 );
    }
    return (sumSearch(a, n-1, x-a[n-1]) || sumSearch(a, n-1, x));
```

So from what I gather... does the third parameter even matter? Since return x==0 doesn't matter for the worst case, it would be O(n) calls since n-1 is done so the worst time complexity can only be O(n)? Is this the correct line of thinking?

Comment: Is that line meant to have calls to `subSearch`, or is there another function `sumSearch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, considering this type of problem is NP-Complete, I think we can rule out a time complexity of O(n).   I think this algorithm has a worst case time of O(2^n).  If you imagine the calls like a tree, each "level" of the tree has twice as many calls as the level before it, which of course comes out to O(2^n).

Comment: This would be true if `||` didn't short-circuit, which certainly makes the analysis easier. But you can put a tighter bound on it

Comment: @JasonBaker I'm assuming the worst case is that `||` doesn't short circuit, since the left side would never find a sum and therefore always return false.

Comment: You're right, I was overthinking it. I had to draw it out, but you're right